# Use Jinja to dynamically generate form inputs and labels from python list

Tags: python, html, jinja2

How to use `Jinja2` to dynamically generate form inputs and labels from list? For example, say I have lists:

```
A = ["name", "city", "state","phone"]
B = ["album", "artist", "genre"]
C = ["title","author","category", "subcategory"]
```

And there are buttons labeled `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to dynamically generate a form depending on which button was clicked. So if `B` was clicked, I want to use items in B to dynamically generate:

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="album" class="col-2 col-form-label">album</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="album">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="artist" class="col-2 col-form-label">artist</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="artist">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="genre" class="col-2 col-form-label">genre</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="genre">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your lists...

I'd expect dictionaries, for starters, but if those are lists I would expecto to see, for example, B = ["Ten", "Pearl Jam", "Grunge"], right?

Comment: yeah, for example B = ["Ten", "Pearl Jam", "Grunge"]

Comment: Probably this is solution: https://gist.github.com/doobeh/5d0f965502b86fee80fe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your situation right I think this is a viable solution.

Python example file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


B = ["Ten","Pearl Jam","Grunge"]

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('stuff.html', my_list=B)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Template example file:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test</title>
<div class=page>
  <h1>Data</h1>

  <form>
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="album" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{my_list[0]}}</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="album">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="artist" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{my_list[1]}}</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="artist">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="genre" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{my_list[2]}}</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="genre">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



</div>
```

Template example for a for loop:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test</title>
<div class=page>
  <h1>Data</h1>

    {% for item in my_list %}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: This solution is a viable solution but the input boxes/labels are defined to be three. Can it be dynamic instead of three?

Comment: Sure, you can use a for loop.

I will update with a simple example.

Comment: This is the reason why I was suggesting a dictionary instead of a list

Comment: Could you please show an example of how using dictionary would have been better to create the inputs dynamically?

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your current code if you need more precise help

Comment: I see what you mean. A jinja template for every button.

Comment: Yes, that would be a viable solution.
Or simply add a similar "if" to your template and solve the issue using a single template .

Comment: @Pitto "Template example" doesn't have input fields, could you correct this example? I am looking for solution of this. It can be both dicts or lists, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @qewg Hello there! Feel free to ask another question and I will write new code there...